# OpenVPN up directive not working

Tags: centos, openvpn, bridge, selinux

I'm having trouble setting up OpenVPN on my server running CentOS 6.2. I have used OpenVPN on this server before and it worked (although that was with Ubuntu, now I'm using CentOS). I just reformatted the hard drive and am trying to get OpenVPN up and running again. I use the `up` and `down` directives in my OpenVPN config file to setup my bridge. For some reason when the `up` script runs, I get a permission denied error when trying to execute `brctl`. Here's my config file:

```
mode server
tls-server

local 192.168.1.93 ##ip of server
port 1194
proto tcp

dev tap0
up "/etc/openvpn/up.sh br0"
down "/etc/openvpn/down.sh br0"

persist-key
persist-tun

ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh1024.pem
#tls-auth ta.key 0

cipher BF-CBC
comp-lzo

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
server-bridge 192.168.1.93 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.110 192.168.1.120
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN nyc.rr.com"
max-clients 10

user nobody
group nogroup
keepalive 10 120
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

And here's the `up.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

BR=$1
DEV=$2
MTU=$3
/sbin/ifconfig $DEV mtu $MTU promisc up
/usr/sbin/brctl addif $BR $DEV
```

`brctl` works fine outside of this script. I'm able to execute it manually.

I start OpenVPN as root, so I don't think permissions in the issue, so that's why I'm so confused.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Here's the error that's echoed:

`[root@server openvpn]# /etc/init.d/openvpn start
Starting openvpn: /etc/openvpn/up.sh: line 7: /usr/sbin/brctl: Permission denied
                                                           [FAILED]`

Comment: Is there anything in `/var/log/messages` or `audit`? Checked `selinux`?

Comment: This is logged in `messages`: `WARNING: Failed running command (--up/--down): external program exited with error status: 126`

Comment: Nothing in `audit`. And what do you mean by "checked `selinux`?

Comment: Error `126` is "not executable". Have you `chmod +x`ed the script?

Comment: Yup, same problem. I also realized I forgot to post the error. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you hit [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=820339).

Create file openvpnlocal.te:

```
module openvpnlocal 1.0;
require {
    type openvpn_t;
    type brctl_exec_t;
    class file { read execute open execute_no_trans };
}
#============= openvpn_t ==============
allow openvpn_t brctl_exec_t:file { read execute open execute_no_trans };
```

Then run:

```
checkmodule -M -m -o openvpnlocal.mod openvpnlocal.te
semodule_package -o openvpnlocal.pp -m openvpnlocal.mod
semodule -i openvpnlocal.pp
```